# Android Share Content feature

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I want to implement a share function like the camera app is using.

```
final Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);    
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent , "Send .."));
```

works perfectly fine I get all the same apps as in the camera app, like facebook and peep. Now I don't want to share an image but only some text, so I change to

```
sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
```

All I can share to now is GMail. So facebook and peep are not registered to plain/text, of course that could be, but makes no sense at all. I rather assume that I have to set some other option.

Anyone an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the type to "text/plain" :

```
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
```